# What causes Apple Mail body to sometimes not display

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, data-transfer

There are a number of similar questions, but this seems not to be a rebuild database or restart problem.

Occasionally, a message in Mail will only show the header, the body does not show up. I used to exit and restart Mail and this would enable that message to show. Now, I find that sometimes I can (using up/down arrow) display another message and then return to the blank message and it will now show up.

If the arrow does not do it, then clicking the header line of another message in a different thread will usually work. Also double-click on the header line opens another window with the message successfully displayed.

What is it that has prevented the body from being displayed? Is there any debug log for the UI?

Macmini7,1 "Late 2014"; MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave; Mail Version 12.4 (3445.104.11); Use classic layout ON